# Is there a way to show the first value of the formula Countif (H7)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get the 1st value based on the criteria of cell H7 (Countif). I have tried using Index Match but I got no luck as it does not accept <> sign.

- **NOT WORKING:**

```
{=INDEX(range1,MATCH(1,(A1=range2)*(B1=range3)*(C1=range4),0))}
```

Sample Data

[image]

Comment: so your tried: `=INDEX($E$2:$E$7,MATCH(1,($B$2:$B$7=H3)*($C$2:$C$7=H4)*($D$2:$D$7>=H3),0))`? unless you have Office 365 this needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: If you have Office 365: `=@FILTER($E$2:$E$7,($B$2:$B$7=H3)*($C$2:$C$7=H4)*($D$2:$D$7>=H3))`

Comment: One more way, if you have O365: `=XLOOKUP(H3&H4&H5,$B$3:$B$7&$C$3:$C$7&INT($D$3:$D$7),$E$3:$E$7)`

Comment: @ScottCraner your 1st answer worked! but I've changed the formula to H5 as that's the needed criteria but it worked!

=INDEX($E$2:$E$7,MATCH(1,($B$2:$B$7=H3)*($C$2:$C$7=H4)*($D$2:$D$7>= **H5** ),0)) and Ctrl-Shift-Enter